# Show that $f(z) = \ln r + i \varphi$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

I am faced with the following problem:

Let $z_{0}\neq 0$ and let $f(z) = \ln r + i \varphi$, where $r = |z|$, $\varphi \in arg z$, and $\varphi$ is chosen so that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$.

Being differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$ means that it's analytic there, right? It sounds to me like the problem is asking me to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $z_{0}$, but I'm not sure how the continuity of $f$ fits in here.

Could someone please let me know what exactly I am being asked to do here? I'm very confused and am not sure how to begin, other than just applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form, at least.

Comment: You can also note that $f(z) = log(z)$, which is analytic everywhere except it's branch-cut.

Comment: Here is the story of $\phi$: it is equal to $arctan(y/x)$ up to $2\pi$ times integer (if $x\neq 0$). It doesn't matter which integer you pick, but you are not allowed to just randomly change these extra integers around and get a discontinuity. Otherwise, regardless of the extra integer, the partials are the same, and you just get to verify CR equations. If the real part of $z_0$ is zero, so you can't make $x\neq 0$ in a neighborhood, then you can use something like $arctan(x/y)$ plus a constant for $\phi$.

Comment: @LevBorisov, so is that what it means by "$\varphi$ is chosen so that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$"? I.e., that $\varphi$ is chosen so that $x \neq 0$? Now, I'm thinking about how I should write up my solution...

Comment: @LevBorisov, or whoever is reading, this is how my solution looks: I checked the CR-equations, and they hold for $r = |z| \neq 0$. At $z_{0}$, this certainly is the case; therefore, $f$ is analytic at $z_{0}$.  Now, since $\varphi \in arg z$ is chosen so that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$, this means that for $\varphi = \arctan \frac{y}{x} + 2 \pi n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \neq 0$, and we will not be dealing with $\ln r$ at any of its branch cuts where it is discontinuous and hence not differentiable. Is this correct/complete?